# Pdf viewer for my angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdfviewer

Is there any pdf viewer component for to see pdf in my angular app. I am tried [angular-pdfjs-viewer](https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer) but it does not work well. I have only a link to pdf file in server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display the pdf using an iframe inside your application, have the url in a  **`$scope`** variable as below

$scope.yourURL = "pdfUrl";

Then

```
<iframe src="{{yourURL | trustAsResourceUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Also you need to use the above filter.

```
.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}])
```